How to avoid record duplication for an item?
The error, I am observing, I try to put the old value i.e already stored. However, the case is, the old value get plucked with its own id, eachtime.

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 UNIQUE constraint failed: tags.name (Connection: sqlite, SQL: insert into "tags" ("name", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (laravel, 1, 2024-12-13 05:16:56, 2024-12-13 05:16:56))

Here is what I am trying
$tag_ids = [];
foreach($tag_names as $tag_name) {//tag_names is array of tags
          
  $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate([ //Tag is a Model
    'name'      => $tag_name,
    'user_id'   => auth()->id(),
  ]);
 
  if($tag) {
    $tag_ids[] = $tag->id;
  }
}

Here is the Tag Model
class Tag extends Model {
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

Here is the migration
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->string('name')->unique();
   $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
   $table->timestamps();
});


If it's a new project and you dont mind migrating from fresh then add your migration for the table tags where you are setting the unique constraint.

To synchronise the tags you can use a single query insertOrIgnore() and use another one to retrieve the ids.
$to_be_upserted = [];
foreach($tag_names as $tag_name) {
    $to_be_upserted[] = ['name' => $tag_name, 'user_id' => auth()->id()];
}
Tag::query()->insertOrIgnore($to_be_upserted, []);
//here all the tags are present in DB

$tag_ids = Tag::query()->where('user_id', auth()->id())
    ->whereIn('name', $tag_names)
    ->pluck('id')->toArray();


If you get the mass assignment exception. You will need to add the fields name and user_id to the Tag model fillable attribute.
class Tag extends Model
{
    $fillable = ['name','user_id'];
//...
}

Edit:
For your issue with the database, you should not have a unique constraint on the field name in the table tags since you want the name to be unique only to a specific user.
You can correct that in the existing migration if you can migrate from fresh.
If you can't then add this new migration
Schema::table('tags', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->dropUnique(['name']);
    $table->unique('name', 'user_id');
});


helped in fetching the tags from taggables with just a little modification.

@SadanKhan Your issue with the error is that you have a key (unique) index on the field name but you want for each user to have his own tags. If you give me the constraint name i can write you an example of the migration.

@SadanKhan added your solution in the edit section

Yea, the problem was integrity constraint. On name it was unique, so if the data is present with same name and same id, which was working but different in id creating the conflict of this type.

I see that you want to collect tag_id based on tag_name, so as stated here, I suggest something using firstOrCreate as follows
$tag_ids = [];
foreach($tag_names as $tag_name) {//tag_names is array of tags
          
  $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(
    ['name'      => $tag_name],
    ['user_id'   => auth()->id()]
  );
 
  if($tag) {
    $tag_ids[] = $tag->id;
  }
}

by doing this, it will find by name or create it with name and user_id.

I have been trying this, and it is working fine when the tag is not available with id. But here the problem is avoid the creating of tag which you see in the error.

can you share us your tag model? for reference

sure, tag model has got user method and fillable property. the migration has got name and user_id referencing the User model.

well.. if you don't mind, can you please edit your question and show us the model?

Added the Migration as well.

have you really tried with my codes? cause I've tried to reproduce your code and compare it with my code. my codes should work just fine.

notice how I set the 'optional' second array argument inside firstOrCreate()

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
